# install julia packages via command line

Tags: docker, julia

I'm wondering if it's possible to run arbitrary julia code via the command like similar to python:

```
python -c "print('stuff')"
```

or in R:

```
R -e '# do stuff'
```

because I'm building a docker container I'd like to be able to do something as shown above for Julia, currently I think I might be able to work around it like so:

```
&& echo 'packs=["Distributions", "CSV", "DataFrames", "ForwardDiff", "PyCall", "GLM"];for i in packs;Pkg.add(i);end' >> packs.jl \
&& julia packs.jl \
```

in the dockerfile, but then I wonder what if packages ask for permission like cario for example

Comment: `julia --help` suggests the `--eval` (or `-e`) option

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following seems to work in Julia 0.6:

```
julia -e 'Pkg.add("DifferentialEquations.jl")'
```

With Julia 0.7-beta, it looks like you should do

```
julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("DifferentialEquations.jl")'
```

For multiple packages, you can use the dot suffix and provide a list.

```
Pkg.add.(["DifferentialEquations.jl", "Optim.jl"])
```

Comment: I am using Powershell and Julia 1.0.0 and I had to use `julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add.([\"DataFrames\"])'` otherwise `"DataFrames"` was interpreted as a variable which is not assigned.

Comment: In Julia version 1.5 you now need to omit the ".jl" in the package name. Thus: `julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("DifferentialEquations")'`